# Recreating the Blog Template

Tags: 2010, development, branding, blog

The blog template allows you to display several blog posts on a page. Clicking on the title allows you to goto a view of the blog post on a seperate page. How would I go about doing something similar from scratch. I want to show multiple items on a page styled in custom way. Clicking on the title should like to an item page where it is styled in the same way.

Comment: Are you looking to do this with a blog list, or another type of list?

Comment: A custom list type. I am happy to do some codding if needed. I just don't know how to tackle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created some similar solutions in the past by using WebPartPages that hold a mixture of ListViews, DataViewWebParts, custom scripts (jquery), etc.  One of the specific things the Blog template does is provide the comments list on the view post page.  That is the sort of a Master/Detail pattern that can be reproduced for others.

I haven't had to do all of that in a template before though.  That would be complicated since all of the datasources and guids would have to be unique to the site.

Answer (score 1):

As I know the Blog template uses XSLT List View Web Part. In past I did the customization of list views by XSL templates. You can see [this simple example](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html) how to use this solution. I hope, it will be helpful.